# F# PInvoke Equivalent

Tags: c#, f#, pinvoke

Given the following C# code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
{
    public int cbSize;
    public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
    public int Flags;
    public int Reserved;
}


[DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData, int DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref int RequiredSize, IntPtr DeviceInfoData);
```

What would the equivalent F# be?

I am assuming it will be something like the following, but I am not sure exactly how to handle the refs.

```
[<Struct;StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA =
    val mutable cbSize: int
    val mutable InterfaceClassGuid: Guid
    val mutable Flags: int
    val mutable Reserved: int

[<DllImport("setupapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)>]
extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA* DeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData, int DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, int* RequiredSize, IntPtr DeviceInfoData)
```

**Edit**
Had the wrong method in the F# section

Comment: Any reason you don't just write it in C#? I heard they both compile to MSIL and they can reference each other.

Comment: I could do that, but then I wouldn't learn how to do it in F#. ;)

Comment: @Aron what a completely unhelpful comment.